# Digital to Analog (DAC) design with MOS transistors

Tags: digital-logic, analog, converter, dac

I am looking for a DAC design wıth NMOS and PMOS transistors as a part of a project, most of the DAC circuits that I found were builted with R-2R or with capacitors. But I need a design with MOS transistor since the porject will be implemented on Cadence and space consideration is important. DAC will be used both in 8-bit SAR ADC and in smooting filter. Sample block diagram of the project is given below, ı could not find appropriate design for DAC. Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: This question is very broad. DAC designs are often proprietary, meaning owned by the company that designed it. You should have a look in literature (IEEE journals etc.) to see how CMOS DACs are generally made. Do you have **any** experience in designing analog circuits? Most CMOS processes not only have MOS transistors but also resistors. You sound inexperienced in the field of DAC design, then designing one will be a project on its own.

Comment: Replace the resistors in your R-2R ladder with mosfets and you got your DAC.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into a current steering DAC. It is basically a differential pair (5Pack) amplifier. Razavi has a introductory paper on this in his Circuit for all seasons issue.

This is the IEEE link:
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8275558

This should be the same uploaded on the UCLA website:
http://www.seas.ucla.edu/brweb/papers/Journals/BRWinter18DAC.pdf

However, these DACs are very high speed and consume a lot of power even when idle.
You may not meet the power budget of your project using this architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdGebo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>